# Outlook - suspend incoming mails

Tags: microsoft-outlook

we are using Outlook 2013 with a hosted exchange from microsoft (cloud service). For productivity reasons, outlook should only fetch new mails at specific times (f.e. 9.00 a.m. and 4.00 p.m.) or at least at a defined intervall (f.e. 300 minutes). Outgoing mails should be send immedeatly.

What we've tried so far:

- Let Outlook closed. Problem: You can't write an outgoing mail or have a look at the calendar without opening outlook having it fetching all incoming mails.
- Disable automatic send/receive. Problem: This setting is not used, if the account is an exchange account. Works only with pop/imap accounts
- Using an imap account. Problem: You can't access calendar and adressbook anymore, rules are not synced with the server, ...
- Using an outlook plugin. Problem: There is only one plugin, which supports this feature: "email prioritizer" from microsoft. This plugin does not work with outlook 2013. It is not supported since 2009.

The question is: How can we solve our problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If there is not an add-on that exists, then It sounds like you will have to write your own add-on, in order to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

No way to do that automatically out of the box. The only way I can see is a manual mode: you can switch to Offline mode on "Send/Receive" ribbon tab (Work Offline button). And go to online at the specific hours / periodically.